# MySQL Query across 40,000 rows v/s one time load and for loop

Tags: mysql, sql, caching

I have a table which has 40,000 rows. From code side around at same exact second about 20,000 users will need to run a query to find their related row. What is better approach here ?

Loading all 40,000 rows in cache and running a for loop on them to find record ? 
Simply query database.

Here is what query will look like. Where parameter will be users IP.

```
SELECT * FROM iplist where ipfrom <= INET_ATON('xxx.xxx.xx.xx') limit 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL already caches the data, in the form of the [InnoDB Buffer Pool](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-buffer-pool.html). As pages of data and indexes are requested, they are copied to RAM, and used for any subsequent queries.

You should define an index for the column you search on, if you don't already have an index or a primary key defined for that column:

```
ALTER TABLE iplist ADD INDEX (ipfrom);
```

Then searching for a specific value in that column won't require a table-scan, it will narrow down the search efficiently.

Note when you use LIMIT, you should also use ORDER BY, otherwise the row you get will be the first one read in index order, which may not always be what you want. If you use ORDER BY redundantly (i.e. the same order it reads the index), then it will be optimized out.

```
SELECT * FROM iplist where ipfrom <= INET_ATON(?) ORDER BY ipfrom LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: they cant use the primary key for this field. There will be many entries from the same IP. But your answer is great +1

Comment: Yes, I expect so in this case, but I wanted to mention the primary key for completeness. One doesn't need to create a new index if the column is already the leftmost column of the primary key.